# Dealing with Image Pixelation During Image Reconstruction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am searching for a technique to utilize a pretrained model for making predictions on images that have larger dimensions compared to the images used for training. The approach involves padding the image to adjust its size proportionally to the model, dividing it into smaller patches, making predictions for each patch, and subsequently reconstructing the complete image. Unfortunately, I am encountering a significant problem where a grid-like pattern emerges despite applying a specific stride. Could you assist me in resolving this issue?

Here is the function that implements the aforementioned approach:

```
def prediction(model, image, TF_record_input_shape):

    height, width, channel = TF_record_input_shape
    h_img, w_img, _ = image.shape

    n = 128
    stride_x = n
    stride_y = n

    ph, pw = (h_img + (n-1)) // n * n - h_img, (w_img + (n-1)) // n * n - w_img

    phh = ph // 2 + (ph % 2)
    phw = ph // 2

    pwh = pw // 2 + (pw % 2)
    pww = pw // 2

    padded_img = image
    if pw != 0 or ph != 0:
        padded_img = np.pad(image, ((phh, phw), (pwh, pww), (0, 0)), 'reflect')
    h_img_p, w_img_p, _ = padded_img.shape
    times = []
    reconstructed_img = np.zeros_like(padded_img)
    overlapped_pixels = np.zeros_like(padded_img)

    for i in range(0, h_img_p - height + 1, stride_x):
        for j in range(0, w_img_p - width + 1, stride_y):
            start_row, start_col = i, j
            end_row, end_col = start_row + height, start_col + width
            img_part = padded_img[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col]
            img_part = np.expand_dims(img_part, axis=0)
            start_time = time.time()
            result_part = model.predict(img_part)
            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            times.append(elapsed_time)
            reconstructed_img[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] += result_part[0]
            overlapped_pixels[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] += 1
    overlapped_pixels = np.where(overlapped_pixels == 0, 1, overlapped_pixels)

    reconstructed_img = reconstructed_img / overlapped_pixels

    #reconstructed_img = reconstructed_img[:h_img, :w_img, :]

    if pw != 0 or ph != 0:
        img_predicted = reconstructed_img[phh: h_img+phh, pwh: w_img+pwh, :]
    else:
        img_predicted = reconstructed_img

    return np.clip((img_predicted + 0.5) * 255.0, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8), times
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I require images with high resolution, so I cannot use resize...